# Discord js - Get bot count on server

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot that shows you how many members and bots you have.

The members part is already done by using the `guild.memberCount` function, but the problem here is the bot count.

This is the code I am trying to use:

`const memberCountWithOnlyBots = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size`

I see this everywhere online but it just doesn't work for me. I have 14 bots on my server but it only returns 1

The weird thing is, if I change the code to `member => !member.user.bot` it still only returns 1, even though there are 5 actual users on the server

Comment: Sometimes, the members might not be cached. So try adding `await message.guild.members.fetch()` right before the line where you declare the `memberCountWithOnlyBots` variable

Comment: Yessss that was the problem! Thank you!